# CMake не работает должным образом

Tags: cmake

Доброго времени суток!
Пытаюсь собрать клиент эфира. Сделал клон с репозитория, собираю согласно тому, что написано в README.

Клон клиента эфира находится по пути /home/mine/cpp-ethereum

Очередной шаг в инструкции:

```
mkdir build; 
cd build               # Create a build directory.
cmake ..               # Configure the project.
cmake --build          # Build all default targets.
```

Когда прописываю:

```
cmake ..
```

Выводится сообщение следующего вида:

```
 CMake Error: The source directory "/home/mine" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

С CMake раньше не работал. Делаю всё согласно инструкции. Как быть в моей ситуации?

Comment: Вместо `cmake ..` прописывайте полный путь до корня исходников эфира.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Выполняя команду `cmake ..` Вы находитесь в неверном каталоге, Вы что-то напутали с тем, где Вы выполняете вышеозначенные команды.